# Android bluetooth connection with an obd2

Tags: android, bluetooth, obd-ii

Till now my app can discover make discoverable and all these. When I press the device's name for example of my near cellphone(which I have opened the bluetooth) it appears in my listview fact that I want.After when I press it, I have the classic error `<< "W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1 ">>`. It doesn't work the bluetoothSocket.connect in my code.

In other case when I go into my car with my tablet(which includes my app from android studio) I can search the obd2 and when I press it ,it makes the bond requirement. I am keying in the 1234 password and make the bond in tablets bluetooth features where I can see it. I need someone who have did something like this to help me to the next steps. For example how to send a command for rpm or speed and take response. Please help me!

Here is my code:

```
public class BluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG ="msg" ;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    private ListView listview;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private static final int MESSAGE_READ =1;
    private static final int ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    private static final int DISCOVERABLE_DURATION = 300;
    private final static UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // Whenever a remote Bluetooth device is found
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                adapter.add(bluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n"
                        + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            //uuid=BluetoothDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid();
        }
    };
   // IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

   // registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter) // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);

        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


        //Listview Item Click Listener
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String itemValue = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);
                BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
                // Initiate a connection request in a separate thread
                ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice);
                t.start();
            }
        });

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    }

    //Οταν πατάμε το button για να ανοίξει το bluetooth!
    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

        adapter.clear();

        ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) view;
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Η συσκευή δεν υποστηρίζει bluetooth.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            toggleButton.setChecked(false);
        } else {

            if (toggleButton.isChecked()){ // to turn on bluetooth
                if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    // A dialog will appear requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth
                    Intent enableBluetoothIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBluetoothIntent, ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Η Συσκευή είναι έτοιμη για χρήση." +
                                    "\n" + "Ανίχνευση για Απομακρυσμένες Συσκευές...",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // To discover remote Bluetooth devices
                    discoverDevices();
                    // Make local device discoverable by other devices
                    makeDiscoverable();
                }
            } else { // Turn off bluetooth

                bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                adapter.clear();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Η συσκευή έχει Απενεργοποιηθεί.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE) {

            // Bluetooth successfully enabled!
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Το Bluetooth έχει Ενεργοποιηθεί." +
                                "\n" + "Ανίχνευση για Απομακρυσμένες Συσκευές...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // To discover remote Bluetooth devices
                discoverDevices();

                // Make local device discoverable by other devices
                makeDiscoverable();
                  // Start a thread to create a  server socket to listen
                // for connection request
                ListeningThread t = new ListeningThread();
                t.start();


            } else { // RESULT_CANCELED as user refused or failed to enable Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Το Bluetooth δεν έχει Ενεργοποιηθεί.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Turn off togglebutton
                toggleButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE){

            if (resultCode == DISCOVERABLE_DURATION){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Η συσκευή είναι τώρα Ανιχνεύσιμη απο άλλες συσκευές..  " +
                                DISCOVERABLE_DURATION + " Δευτερόλεπτα",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Αποτυχία να Ενεργοποιηθεί η Ανιχνευσημότητα της Συσκευής.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void discoverDevices(){
        // To scan for remote Bluetooth devices
        if (bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ανίχνευση για άλλες Συσκευές Bluetooth...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Η Ανίχνευση Απέτυχε να αρχίσει.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
     //Συνάρτηση για makeDiscoverable
    protected void makeDiscoverable(){
        // Make local device discoverable
        Intent discoverableIntent = new
                Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, DISCOVERABLE_DURATION);
        startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register the BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    }
     //on pause an xreiastei na bei kwdikas{}
     @Override
     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         this.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
     }
    @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bluetooth, menu);
                 return true;
              }
    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //Thread gia ton server..
    private class ListeningThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServerSocket;
       //Constructor
        public ListeningThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket temp = null;
            try {
                temp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(getString(R.string.app_name), uuid);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bluetoothServerSocket = temp;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
            // This will block while listening until a BluetoothSocket is returned
            // or an exception occurs
            Log.d(TAG, "O kwdikas edw trexei");
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection is accepted
                if (bluetoothSocket != null) {
                    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Επιτυχής Σύνδεση με την συσκευή.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }

                    });
                     ConnectedThread  a = new ConnectedThread(bluetoothSocket);
                      a.start();
                    try {
                        bluetoothServerSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                }
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

        private class ConnectingThread extends Thread{
            private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
            private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice ;

            public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device){
                BluetoothSocket temp = null;
                bluetoothDevice = device;
                //Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
                try{
              
           temp=bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bluetoothSocket = temp;

                }


            public void run() {

                // Cancel discovery as it will slow down the connection
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                try {

                    bluetoothSocket.connect();
                    Log.d(TAG, "the code is running");
                    // This will block until it succeeds in connecting to the device
                    // through the bluetoothSocket or throws an exception
                  //  bluetoothSocket.connect();
                    //isConnected = true;
                } catch (IOException connectException) {
                    connectException.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        //unable to connect

                        bluetoothSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException closeException) {
                        closeException.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                //manageConnectedSocket(bluetoothSocket);
                ConnectedThread  t= new ConnectedThread(bluetoothSocket);
                t.start();

            }



        // Cancel an open connection and terminate the thread
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {


        private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private android.os.Handler mHandler;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            bluetoothSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity

                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
        }

        // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        // Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
                mmInStream.close();
                mmOutStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        public void setmHandler(Handler mHandler) {
            this.mHandler = mHandler;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have been able to pair the OBDII adapter that is plugged into the diagnostic port on a vehicle with your phone, but now you need to connect to it.

Connect to the device with:

```
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);

    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    BluetoothSocket socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

    socket.connect();
```

Once you are connected to the device you can initialize the OBDII adapter with AT commands, such as "AT E0" for echo off, and "AT L0" for line-feed off.

You can then continuously get data from the vehicle by issuing the corresponding PID codes: for RPM use "01 0C", for speed use "01 0D".

More detail and discussion can be found at this link:

http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/how-guide-obdii-reader-app-development

Here is a link to a good OBD2 starter library that you can extend and improve for your specialized needs:

https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api